# JBoss 7.3 - org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast to org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8

Tags: java, jboss, ojdbc

I'm working on a legacy web application running on JBoss 7.3, and getting the following exception when the code tries to execute a stored procedure

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast to org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8
        at com.mycompany.mypackage.dao.DAOUtil.executeStoredProc(DAOUtil.java:73)
        at com.mycompany.mypackage.dao.PurgeDAO.getPurgeReason(PurgeDAO.java:37)
        at com.mycompany.mypackage.ejb.purge.PurgeServiceBean.getPurgeReason(PurgeServiceBean.java:54)
```

triggered by the following code

```
String dataSourceSetting = "java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS"
Context oracleContext = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) oracleContext.lookup(dataSourceSetting);
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(storedProcedure);
Connection wrappedConnection = ((WrappedConnectionJDK8) connection).getUnderlyingConnection();
```

What would stop an object from being cast to the same class type?

Answer (score 1):

WrappedConnectionJDK8 is coming from 2 different classloaders. You shouldn't provide it in your application.
Also you could unwrap it, that would be the proper way to get the underlying connection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with a [JBoss Deployment Descriptor](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-deploy/practical-examples-of-jboss-deployment-structure-xml/)

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
   <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
   <deployment name="MyApp.ear">
      <dependencies>
         <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />
         <module name="com.oracle" />
      </dependencies>
   </deployment>
   <sub-deployment name="MyApp-Web.war">
      <exclusions />
      <dependencies>
         <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />
         <module name="com.oracle" />
      </dependencies>
   </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```